# Do or will java.io methods on Android throw InterruptedIOException?

Tags: java, android, exception, interrupted-exception

I understand that there wasn't much of a choice when *InterruptedIOException* was introduced; it had to be a subclass of *IOException*.

The sole existence of *InterruptedIOException* doubtlessly is making life a bit complicated if you want to know whether a thread was interrupted or not. That's because you have to treat *InterruptedIOException* differently from *IOException* if you want to maintain the information that the thread got interrupted.

While *InterruptedIOException* was invented for *java.nio*, there are reports that at least under Solaris, there are *java.io* methods which throw *InterruptedIOException*. Also, with a new Android version, one is at risk that a library migrates from *java.io* to *java.nio* or additional methods get somehow mapped.

I tend to think one should account for *InterruptedIOException* to be on the safe side. How do you see it? Insights, experiences, strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use interrupt if you can avoid it.  For blocking IO operations I would set a volatile flag and close the stream instead.  If the closed flag has been set I ignore any IOException thrown.  This give you more control over how a component is shutdown. Once I set a component to `closed` I don't unset of course and I can check this as often as I like.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Under certain circumstances, using the `closed` information to end a thread does not seem to be possible in a straightforward fashion, though. E.g. if you have a thread that aims at keeping a connection open (and reopening it if it has to be closed).

Comment: If should check the `closed` flag before attempting to re-connect. If the component doesn't do this, it should support a shutdown/stop/close method

Comment: True. Thanks! I'm now neither using interrupts nor exactly close but your assessment of interrupts led me in the right direction.